# LoaderMax in child swf

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, gsap, loadermax

I have 2 child swfs being loaded into a parent swf. Each child swf loads its own XML file. When I load the child swfs, I get back a null because they have not loaded their XML files yet. I am using greensock's LoaderMax. Is there anyway for the parent to know when all the child XMLs have been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't want to count the children when they load, but rather when the children are done loading some XML. Consider first making a class for each/all of your children that will be loading xml, something like:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class ChildToLoad extends MovieClip{

        public function ChildToLoad() {
            // Load xml here, optionally use URLLoader or XMLLoader,
            // but regardless of what you use, listen for when XML load 
            // is complete and handle it with the loadComplete() function
            ...
            someXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
            ...
        }

        private function loadComplete(evt:* = null)
        {
            var padre:MovieClip = parent as MovieClip;
            padre.childLoaded(); // Call function of parent
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your main swf (your parent) do something like:

```
var child1:ChildToLoad = new ChildToLoad();
var child2:ChildToLoad = new ChildToLoad();
addChild(child1);
addChild(child2);

var loadedChildrenCount:int = 0;

function childLoaded() // Called by all children after they load XML
{
    trace("childLoaded()");
    loadedChildrenCount++;

    if(loadedChildrenCount == 2)
    {
        trace("All children have loaded! Do Stuff!");
    }
}
```

However; If I read too much into your question ...

LoaderMax has a `onChildComplete` handler you can use

> A handler function for LoaderEvent.CHILD_COMPLETE events which are
>   dispatched each time one of the loader's children (or any descendant)
>   finishes loading successfully. Make sure your onChildComplete function
>   accepts a single parameter of type LoaderEvent
>   (com.greensock.events.LoaderEvent).

You can try something like:

```
var childrenLoadedCount:int = 0;
var queue:LoaderMax = new LoaderMax({
    onChildComplete:AChildWasLoaded,
    TODO:AddYourOtherArgumentsHere
}); 
...
function AChildWasLoaded(evt:LoaderEvent) 
{
    childrenLoadedCount++;
    if(childrenLoadedCount = 2)
    {
        // All children have loaded
    }
}
```

[Read the docs for more options](http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/_loadermax.html)